# Charge no VAT for Canary Islands (Categorised as Spain)

Tags: vat

I've been trying to find an answer to how I disable VAT for anybody who orders from the Canary Islands. A customer made an order from the Tenerife over the weekend and is a little unhappy he's paying VAT. The trouble is that customers who order from the Canaries use Spain as their country, which is correct. *Spain however, is charged at normal VAT Rates... The Canaries are not*

What's the best way to fix this issue? I don't have any knowledge in Magento programming and would rather not tamper with things I know little about...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://zipcodes.guide-spain.com/Canary_Islands there are two postcode prefixes for the canaries, Las Palmas 35 & Santa Cruz de Tenerife 38. Assuming I've understood that correctly then:

In admin `Sales/Tax/Manage Tax Zones & Rates` you've probably got a tax rate for Spain setting it to your standard tax rate. Click `add new tax rate` call it something similar to the Spain one, but put 35* in the post code, and set the rate to zero. Do the same for 38*. 
You could also set the state/region here, but only if your store will require that in the address to select. Then in `Sales/Tax/Manage Tax Rules` you probably have a rule called something like `standard vat` which matches *customer & product tax classes* with *tax rates*. Edit it to add in your new tax rates in the multiselect.

You can test it in the basket using `get a quote` changing the post code to see when it adds/removes VAT